# Error while running the ceylon tutorial code

Tags: ceylon

I'm following this [tutorial](http://renatoathaydes.github.io/Learn-Programming-In-Ceylon-Part-1) which is giving me this code:

```
"Run the module `hello.ceylon`."
shared void run() {
    process.write("Enter a number (x): ");
    value userX = process.readLine();
    value x = parseFloat(userX);
    process.write("Enter a number (y): ");
    value userY = process.readLine();
    value y = parseFloat(userY);

    if (exists x, exists y) {
        print("``x`` * ``y`` = ``x * y``");
    } else {
        print("You must enter numbers!");
    }
}
```

But it gives me this message:

Argument must be assignable to parameter string of parseFloat: String? is not assignable to String

I have copy/paste'd this code but still the same message.

Answer (score 3):

I am the author of the tutorial.

I'm terribly sorry that this sample code does not work anymore (it worked with Ceylon 1.0.0, see below).

I have fixed it in the tutorial and created a [runnable sample](https://try.ceylon-lang.org/?gist=9582dbcbc19ee6ee4859420050b48f05) in the Ceylon Web IDE which you can use to try this out.

Basically, the problem is that, as Lucas Werkmeister pointed out, [readLine()](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.2.2/module-doc/api/process.object.html#readLine) return a `String?` which is equivalent to `String|Null` because it may not be possible to read anything from the input (user's keyboard), in which case you get `null` back.

The code sample worked with Ceylon 1.0.0 because `readLine()` used to return a `String`.

So for the code to compile, you need to make sure to check that what you got back `exists` (ie. is NOT `null`):

```
value userX = process.readLine();
value x = parseFloat(userX else "");
```

When you do `userX else ""`, you tell Ceylon that if `userX` exists, it should use that, if not, use `""` instead. This way, we always get a `String` back...

The whole code snippet should look like this (see the sample linked to above):

```
process.write("Enter a number (x): ");
value userX = process.readLine();
value x = parseFloat(userX else "");
process.write("Enter a number (y): ");
value userY = process.readLine();
value y = parseFloat(userY else "");

if (exists x, exists y) {
    print("``x`` * ``y`` = ``x * y``");
} else {
    print("You must enter numbers!");
}
```

Thank you for reporting the error! Hope you enjoy the rest of the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

`process.readLine()` returns a `String?`, that is, a `String` if it could read a line, or `null` if not (for example, end of stream). `parseFloat` requires a non-optional `String`: `parseFloat(null)` is not allowed. So you have to `assert` that `userX` exists:

```
assert (exists userX = process.readLine());
```

or

```
value userX = process.readLine();
assert (exists userX);
```

Both forms make `userX` a non-optional variable.